# Converting text to number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a online form which a user selects duration of class from a dropdown list.  This data then goes into a database field called duration - varchar(5), a data example would be 02:30.  Then I run a stored procedure which should convert the data to 2.5 This allows for calculation of duration with hourly rate of pay.

**DataFields** 
Duration - varchar(5) 02:30 
ValueOfDuration - numeric(18,2) 2.5

My problem is I am getting an error when this stored procedure runs. 
Error converting data type varchar to real.

```
UPDATE 
ManualAdjustments
SET 
ValueOfDuration = ROUND (CONVERT(real, LEFT(Duration, 2))+(CONVERT(real,RIGHT(Duration, 2)) / 60.0),2) 
WHERE ValueOfDuration IS NULL
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If you are using Oracle, use TO_NUMBER instead of CONVERT.

Comment: works fine sqlserver for 2:30 value .. is there a particular value for which its not working ?

Comment: Are you sure all your durations have the format of HH:MM ? if your left would catch that ':' you'd face that conversion error.

Comment: Lots of product specific functions there. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL server magement studio 2012

Comment: It would be much more appropriate to store your duration as a number in the first place rather than `VARCHAR(5)` - [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @GarethD I have to store it as a varchar because its not a number its a time format.  Maybe i should store it as datetime but then how do i convert that to number

Comment: Duration is a number (as proven by your requirement to convert to a number), not a time. I am simply saying store the numeric "2.5" rather than "02:30" in the first place. You may wish to borrow time format to display it, but it is not a time. If something takes 26 hours to complete, you cannot use the time format to display "26:00" because it is not a valid number. Store it as seconds/minutes/hours/years, whatever interval is appropriate for the duration you are recording (don't store cooling times in years, or time since the Jurassic period in seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Database is SQL Server

```
UPDATE 
ManualAdjustments
SET 
ValueOfDuration= CAST(DATEDIFF(minute,'1990-1-1','1990-1-1 '+Duration)/60.0 AS NUMERIc(15,2))
WHERE ValueOfDuration IS NULL
```

Comment: Do i need to change the datatype for valueOfDuration?

Comment: Duration is varchar(5) but ValueofDuration is numeric(18.2)

Comment: Getting this error now, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Duration is varchar(5) and ValueofDuration is numberic(18,2)

Comment: Duration is made up by this so it needs to be a varchar. Duration.Value = ddlHoursHR.SelectedValue + ":" + ddlMinsHR.SelectedValue;

Comment: It will always be in that format as the user picks from dropdown list, one dropdown list is for hours and then the other is for minutes and then they get combind and inserted into database which is happening when as i can see it sitting in back end table but when conversion runs it doesnt like it.

Comment: ok Maximum value for ddlMinsHR.SelectedValue it should be 59, is it ?

Comment: Thanks so much was doing a silly thing, i had it going up to 100 which doesnt make sense and then was over limit for field.

Comment: Glad to help you !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server AND your Duration does not exceed 59:59

```
Update YourTable Set ValueOfDuration  =  DateDiff(SS,'1900-01-01','1900-01-01 00:'+Duration)/60.
```

In this case 02:30 would return 2.5

Comment: Nothing happens dont get error but also doesnt update field.

Comment: @Alexandria Forgive the dumb question, but did you include the decimal after the 60?  60.

Comment: I didnt should i have?

Comment: @Alexandria Without the decimal it is an INT/INT which could easily generate a zero

Comment: @Alexandria Yes please.   Or even make it 60.0 to be more clear/readable

Comment: @Alexandria Good to know. Cheers

Comment: Both you guys have similar answers

Comment: Worked fine locally but when i put it on server i get this error. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Alexandria I suspect a data issue (ie malformed data).  Perhaps use try_convert(datetime,duration)

Comment: @Alexandria Being "Time" data, Select Distinct Duration from YourTable Order by 1...  See if anything catches your attention